# How to create winform login dialog and keep looping

Tags: c#, .net

Creating a login form that will then proceed to the main form if the credentials are correct.  Here is the basic pseudocode:

```
ShowLoginForm()

if (DialogResult == OK)
  CheckCredentials();
  if (credentials == VALID)
    ShowMainForm();
  else
    LoopBackAndShowLoginFormAgain();  //repeat process...
else
  CloseLoginForm();
```

However, I'm relatively new to WinForms and still figuring it out.  I'm trying to decide where to put my loop (Main() or somewhere in LoginForm).  Where should I make the check for credentials?  This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new AutoSignerForm());
    }
}
```

I don't want to exit and open up a login form repeatedly (am looking for some efficiency here so I want to use the same login dialog).  Any pointers, tips, or ideas?

Comment: Instead of displaying a new form if login fails, what about handling the logic in the Submit button handler? If credentials don't check out, clear the username/password fields and don't close the form.

Comment: This was kind of the idea I had too.  I didn't know how to prevent closing the form and returning a dialogResult back to Main.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would do the following:

- in Program.cs show the loginForm as a dialog

  ```
  LoginForm login_form = new LoginForm();
  if(login_form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      Application.Run(new MainForm());
  }
  ```
- in LoginDialog, handle the click event on "Login" button (or whatever is named)

  ```
  // replace with the actual login
  if(textBoxUsername.Text == "my user" && textBoxPassword.Text == "my pass") {
     // save the user has logged in somewhere
     // set the dialog result to ok
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
     // close the dialog
     this.Close();
  } else {
     // login failed
     MessageBox.show("Login failed");
     // do not close the window
  }
  ```

Now, you will keep the LoginDialog shown until the user enters valid credentials or he gives up trying and the application closes. This way you will have only one instance of the LoginForm and it will be a nice user experience. 
Also, you can be sure that the MainForm is not initialized and shown without the user logging in successfully.

Comment: This was my same exact idea, however, I couldn't get it to work.  I'm not sure of a way to prevent the form from closing.  With your code a MessageBox shows and then the form closes and the main form is then shown.

Comment: You have probably set the "LoginButton" with DialogResult.OK. You should leave it as DialogResult.None (the default property) and you could also not set it as "AcceptButton" to the form. Can you please check that and try again?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();     
do {
   if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) {
       return; // Ends application
   }
} while (CheckCredentials() != VALID)
Application.Run(new AutoSignerForm());
```

Comment: This works until the user wants to click the cancel button on the login form.  I wanted to make it relatively clean and not have a bunch of boolean values to make checks.

Comment: I changed my example accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, so you recommend checking the credentials inside Main instead of the actual loginForm?

Comment: This is just one possibility. Of cause you could check the credentials in the login form and keep it open until the user either enters valid credentials or clicks `Cancel`. This requires no C# loop statement at all and allows you show an additional message (e.g. by making an unvisible label visible) if the credentials are not valid for example.

Comment: See my answer below.  What you just explain is exactly what I'm doing (I think).  I would like to use the visible label also.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

why not create main form and then show login modal dialog. Then you could check what to do.

Comment: Show change my Main around to show that Application.Run(new AutoSignerForm()) and then within the Form_Load() I bring up a loginDialog?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the DialogResult to None in the SubmitButton event handler?  Something like:

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isValidCredentials())
      DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed to login or some other error");
      DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change it to `if (isValidCredentials()) { DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; Close() } else { messageLabel.Visible = true; firstTextBox.Focus(); }`. In the second case no dialog result is required, since the dialog form remains open. Only in `cancelButton_Click` do `DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; Close();`

Comment: I made the changes, but for some reason when I don't set DialogResult = DialogResult.None in the 2nd case it closes my form.  I haven't set it elsewhere.

Comment: Probably this happens automatically beacause the `loginButton` is the forms default accept button. Keep setting it `None` in this case.

Comment: Bingo, I made the change back to None and it works perfectly.  However, do I still need to call Close()?

Comment: I it works perfectly, don't change it. (Don't change a winning horse!)