# Pop up input box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying make an input box pop up asking the user for a password similar to `messagebox.show`.  But I want the user to be able to type into the box so I can use the return data to validate.

The system will check if the user has been authenticated if not it will request authentication via pop up.

Comment: Web, WinForm, WPF? What is the platform?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: something like this can be accomplished by doing a simple Google Search here is a link you can use for starters.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140852/how-to-create-winform-login-dialog-and-keep-looping
do a Google search on the following `C# winforms how to create a custom login form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do, assuming you are in WinForms, is create a new form, add a textbox and button to it, then call it if it is not authenticated.

```
public partial class Form1
{
    public void Main()
    {
    bool authenticated = ...

    if(!authenticated)
    {
       Your_Form newForm = new Your_Form();
       newForm.Show(this);
       string password = newForm.Password;
       if(password != "")
           ...
    }
    }
    }

public class Your_Form
{
public TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
// ...
public string Password = "";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Password = textBox1.Text;
}
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to have to assume you are using Winforms, but this code could be converted to WPF or web, too. You need to use `DisplayDialog()` from your parent form, to display your secondary form which is the popup. This will display your new form as a dialog. Most importantly, when it is closed it always sends back a `DialogResult` (explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816145) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dialogresult))to the parent form, which you can use to determine if the user was authenticated. 
[This](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=70285) article explains how to do something very similar to what I think you want